# Waiting for function execution

Tags: javascript

Is a function:

```
function getItem(key) {
    var item;
    func(key, function(items) {
        for (var key2 in items) {
            if (key2 === key && items.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
                item = items[key2];
            }
        }
    });
    return item;
}
```

When we call it, the response we get undefined. How to wait for the callback function execution and only then return the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just introduce a callback as a parameter to your function:

```
function getItem(key, callback) {
  func(key, function(items) {
    for (var key2 in items) {
      if (key2 === key && items.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
        callback(items[key2]);
      }
    }
  });
}

getItem('bob', function (key) {
  console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: How then correctly to satisfy the condition: if(getItem('bob') && getItem('count') === 4) { ... }

Comment: I don't think you can using this method. You'll probably have to use a couple of deferred objects. Plenty of decent modules out there to help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Thats all. Because Javascript have no way to wait for asynchronous callback.

You can reuse the concept of callbacks to return your value instead of returning it directly

```
function getItem(key, callback) {
  var item;
  func(key, function(items) {
    for (var key2 in items) {
      if (key2 === key && items.hasOwnProperty(key2)) {
        item = items[key2];
      }
    }

    callback(item);
  });
}
```

And then use it `getItem('key', function( item ) { ... })`

Comment: how do you know that it is asynchronous ? There's nothing that sort of, in OP's post.

Comment: You have no guarantee it is synchronous, then by definition it is async (Even if in fact it is not)

Comment: See my last comment ... I know that functions can be sync, but if you dont know - assume it is async - can save much time debugging :-)

Comment: How then correctly to satisfy the condition: if(getItem('bob') && getItem('count') === 4) { ... }

Comment: ... Honestly - change the concept . If it is not possible, you can wait two times for both to finish - but it is large example to fit into here

Comment: Really, that should have been the main question. You kind of buried the lede there, OP.